# Javascript ES6 modules not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module, ecmascript-6

I can't figure this out. I have a small app setup with an index.html that includes a javascript file. On the same directory as that file is another file named myJsModule.js with the following code:

```
export default class{

    doStuff()
    {
        console.log("calling goStuff() from external Module");
    }
}
```

The main javascript file that is loaded from the html then does the import in this way:

```
import myJsModule from "myJsModule";
// TESTING MODULES
let myNewModule = new myJsModule();
myNewModule.doStuff();
```

I have a local web server running using Node, so I'm accesing this index.hmtl through my localhost: http://127.0.0.1:8080.

Im getting the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (referring to myJsModule on my main js file). I also tried using babel to transpile this into previous javascript. I had the same problem using the "require".

Shouldn't my local server figure this out? Or am I using this wrong?

Comment: AFAIK no browser natively supports ES6 modules or ES6 module syntax. So in addition to compiling with Babel, you'll also need to use a module bundler like Webpack or Rollup

Comment: @djfdev I think he is using [tag:node.js] not a browser.

Comment: It sounds like he's building a browser app served by NodeJS, so both techincally. But it looks like his error is resulting from the "main JavaScript file loaded from the HTML" so I believe this is his browser giving a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, this is the error I'm getting from Chrome console. If modules are not meant to be run in the browser, are they only designed for js files that are ran on the server? Do I need use Webpack or similar to organize my client scripts then?

Comment: It's just an unfortunate part of the history and implementation of JavaScript. Node has it's own module system, so you can use `require` natively to import a CommonJS style module. ES6 specified a new import/export syntax, but browsers have been slow to implement modules with either syntax (I think maybe Safari is the exception). So in the mean time, best to bundle your browser code with Webpack or otherwise. Modules are really nice to work with, so it's well worth the extra build step.

Comment: Looks like there's actually been more progress on this than I thought, you can read about in [this article](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/) from May. But considering support is still so limited, I think it's going to be quite a while before we can safely use modules in the browser w/o a bundler.

Comment: Apart from the fact that ES6 modules appear not to be supported in your environment, this code doesn't work anyway. You export a class, but after importing you try to use it like an instance. Instead, just `export function doStuff() { …}`, then `import * as myJsModule from "myJsModule";` and call `myJsModule.doStuff();`.

Comment: You are correct, I'm editing my question to avoid confusion. I actually wanted to export the entire class, so I was missing the class instantiation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Chrome 61, modules are [natively supported](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/nic61#modules). I was able to get your example working with the following HTML and JavaScript.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Native Module</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
    <script type="module">
        import MyJsModule from './MyJsModule.js';
        let myJsModule = new MyJsModule();
        myJsModule.doStuff();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

MyJsModule.js:

```
export default class MyJsModule {

    doStuff() {
        console.log("calling doStuff() from external Module");
    }

}
```

Comment: You sure about his? I'm using version 62 of Chrome on Windows and it still won't recognize "import". Did you have to enable anything in your chrome://flags/ ?

Comment: You are right. I was missing the type="module" attribute in the script tag in my html. I didn't actually know I needed this. I have now modules working in chrome. Many thanks.

Comment: Also note - there must be "content-type" response header for modules to work.